# How to add border to a basic card in action on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

As described in action on google website, you can add a border to a basic card.

[Basic Card- Action on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card)

I built a basic card through the code below and it is working

```
 conversation.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: cardText,
    subtitle: product.company_name,
    title: product.name,
    buttons: new Button({
        title: 'View Details',
        url: deeplink_url,
    }),
    image: new Image({
        url: product.image,
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
    }),
}));
```

Action on Google website says you can add border by calling the .setImageDisplay method which accepts a string as its parameter.

Where should I call this method in the above code snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation to which you link is for the original version of the client library. In a version 1 Action of mine I have lines similar to these

```
card = app.buildBasicCard()
.setImage(<image_goes_here>, <alternate>, <width>, <height>)
.setImageDisplay('CROPPED');
```

And in a version 2 Action I have something like these

```
card.image = {};
card.image.url = <image_goes_here>;
card.image.width = <width>;
card.image.height = <height>;
card.image.accessibilityText = <alternate_text>;
card.display = 'CROPPED';
...
card = new BasicCard(card);
```